# Load order while bootstrapping models

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bootstrapping, load-order

In my express app I load the model like so

```
models_path = __dirname + "/models";
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function(file) {
    if (~file.indexOf(".js")) {
      return require(models_path + "/" + file);
    }
});
```

I had two schemas, A and B, and A was calling `mongoose.Schema("B")` at the beginning. It was working perfectly until now. I get `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "B"`. I assume it is b/c A was loaded before B. **So, is there a way to bootstrap my models with a load order ?**.

Comment: use `require` inside model files

Comment: yes, inside file for model that uses it

Comment: That depends on what you mean by clean.  Node will only ever load one version of your module into memory for your process, if you `require` it multiple times it will keep on accessing the same pre-loaded module rather than actually loading it multiple times, so in that sense you should just require it where you need it, even if it might already be loaded.  That has the side benefit of explicitly showing where you expect everything to come from.

Comment: actually it's how you are really supposed to do it, while your "require-all" solution is not.

Comment: @vkurchatkin yeah but it is cleaner for me. And faster and lighter

Comment: But what if both models need each other? Then they'd be requiring each other and it would never load. Seems like a possible paradigm is that models shouldn't use other models?